# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I created a project in the below structure.

```
├──sample
|  ├── main
|  |   ├── init.py
|  |   └── process.py
|  ├── unidata
|  |   ├── __init__.py
|  |   └── function.py
|  └── venv
```

process.py contains the below code.

```
from unidata import function
sample = function.sample()
result = sample.printing()
print(result)
```

And function.py contains

```
class sample:
    def printing(self):
        return 'Done'
```

when I executed it in IDE I am able to get the result. But when I tried with python command I am facing issues.

```
C:\Users\lenovo\eclipse-workspace\sample\main>python process.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 1, in <module>
    from unidata import function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unidata'
```

I am using python3.6

Comment: I tried, this is the error i got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.unidata'; '__main__' is not a package"

Answer (score 1):

In the `sample` directory try running`python3 -m main.process process.py`. You can read more [here](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent).

Answer (score 0):

you need to see the project structure and from where the code is being executed.

to run the code run the command from the sample folder as `python main\process.py`

Comment: Tried, But facing the same issue